# R: Divide values in a dataset by another value that changes when some conditions are met

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset `df` generated by

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = seq(1:9),
    sample = c("SRM1", "SAM1", "SAM2", "SAM3", "SRM2", "SAM4", "SAM5", "SRM3", "SRM4"), 
    ratio1 = rnorm(9, mean = 2, sd = 0.02),
    ratio2 = rnorm(9, mean = 1, sd = 0.01))
```

and looks like

```
 id  sample ratio1  ratio2
 1   SRM1   2.0271  0.99915
 2   SAM1   2.0241  0.98810
 3   SAM2   1.9522  1.00300
 4   SAM3   1.9877  1.00343
 5   SRM2   1.9800  1.00522
 6   SAM4   2.0184  0.97788
 7   SAM5   2.0045  1.00549
 8   SRM3   1.9684  0.99129
 9   SRM4   2.0034  1.00310
```

I have to divide the values reported in the `ratio1` column for `SRM` rows by a fixed number `a = 1.9`. Then I have to divide the values reported in the `ratio1` column for `SAM` rows by the average of the "surrounding" `SRM/a` values.

To give an example: at `id` 1 and 5 there are two `SRM` samples, I calculate `avg1 <- mean(2.2701, 1.9800)/a`. At this point I can calculate

```
df$ratio.corr <- rep(NA, 9)
df$ratio1.corr[c(2:4)] <- df$ratio1[c(2:4)]/avg1
```

For `SAM4` and `SAM5`, `avg2` will be calculated as the average of the `ratio1` values for `SRM2` and `SRM3` samples.

For an hypothetical `SAM6` with `id = 10`, `avg3` will be calculated as the average between the values `ratio1` reported for `SRM4` and the hypothetical `SRM5` sample with i.e. `id = 11`.

Please consider that:

- the real dataset has about 10000 rows;
- `avg` values are always calculated for samples identified with the string `SRM`;
- non-`SRM` samples have many different names without a common string;
- distance from consecutive `SRM` may vary (sometimes is 3, 4 or even 0 rows)
- similar operations are required also for the `ratio2` column but with `b = 0.91` instead of `a`.

It's just driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this possible solution:

```
library(data.table)
a = 1.9
b = 0.91
df <- as.data.table(df)

# SRMs
srm <- grep("SRM", df$sample)
# SAMs between consecutive SRMs
sam <- diff(srm)-1

# Splitting df in SRMs and SAMs
df.srm <- df[srm][, id := 1:.N]
df.sam <- df[-srm]

# For each SAMs I write the IDs of the SRMs before and after it
srm1 <- rep(df.srm$id[-length(df.srm$id)], sam)
srm2 <- srm1 + 1
df.sam <- df.sam[, ':=' (srm1 = srm1, srm2 = srm2)]

# Calculating ratio1/a and ratio2/b
df.srm[, ':=' (ratio1.a = ratio1/a, ratio2.b = ratio2/b)]

# Calculating ratios for each SAMs divided by the average of srm1 and srm2
df.sam$ratio1.ok <- df.sam$ratio1/((df.srm$ratio1.a[df.sam$srm1] + df.srm$ratio1.a[df.sam$srm2])/2)
df.sam$ratio2.ok <- df.sam$ratio2/((df.srm$ratio2.b[df.sam$srm1] + df.srm$ratio2.b[df.sam$srm2])/2)
```

It seems to work but I think that the last two rows are a bit of a mess. Do you know how to improve the code?